# How to set username and password for a PPTP VpnService in Android?

Tags: java, android, vpn, pptp

I'm developing an Android app to establish a PPTP VPN connection to a server.

I've read some code samples and guides like [this](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2014/06/android-vpn-service/) and also I've found that there are some classes like [ToyVpn](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/development/+/master/samples/ToyVpn/src/com/example/android/toyvpn) which implemented android VpnService. I think this samples are based on non-PPTP connection, but I need a guide which shows me the way of establishing a PPTP connection and set username and password for this connection.

Thanks in advace.

Comment: hi did you get ?

Comment: @KrunalIndrodiya hi, I didn't complete that project, any way, I think you need to use jni codes to create PPTP services and Android Java core does not support such an implementation.

Comment: Did you find the answer???

Comment: @mohsen No. As I remember we needed to do something with jni and c++ which potentially may cause some security and root issues. BTW as I said to KrunalIndrodiya that project was deserted because of other problems.